# Developing a searchable database using Drupal

Tags: php, database, drupal, drupal-7

I'm working on a project that involves coming up with a web application that will contain a search-able database for  as the main feature. Ideally, I'm envisaging something that has a similar functionality to that of: http://www.gatesfoundation.org/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database

The database will be populated through a form or an uploaded .csv file which contains the data already per-filled. I'm looking for any leads as to how I can achieve this using the Drupal-7 CMS, including the modules that I can add to aid these type of search features.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of module available to import CSV data into the Drupal. You can use the Drupal's [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds), [import](https://www.drupal.org/project/import), [import CSV data](https://www.drupal.org/project/import_csv_data), [datasources](https://www.drupal.org/project/datasources) or [migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module to import data into the Drupal nodes.

After importing the data into the Drupal system, you could use the Drupal's default search feature to achieve the required layout. I would also suggest to use [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) to manage and customize your search on the site. One thing that you will need to customize the search with Drupal views for the required ajax search or either customize search with your own theme in Drupal.

Hope that help!

Comment: Thanks, I have had a workaround on customizing the views and my search form. However I figured out that the imported data (from the CSV or any other input method) should be able to render on a table after which I can sort or filter this data using filters (Which I have already configured) of course with the search form being there too. I'd like to know if I'm on the right track on achieving that or what extra tweaks do I have to add?

Comment: Are you saving your imported data into a content type or in feeds? Importing into a content type will provide you more flexibility while showing and filtering the day whereas not with feed items.

Comment: If its imported into the node then you are on right track and can use views to configure listing, filtering, sorting etc. Also, can use the search type of views to explore Drupal's Search API.

Comment: Initially, I think I had used feeds to import a csv file, not sure whether it was within a content type. What are my ideal options on how to proceed?

Comment: As I said, import your CSV data into a content type. Your content type should have all fields for mapping with CSV data. Once you done, create views and use the views filter for filtering the data. You can use Facet filters with the search API as well to get the extended filters form.

Answer (score 0):

Use Views module with a page display. Pull the fields or contents for any type and on the filter's section try exposing the filter of what you want to search on. You will also need views data export [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export), and attach the data export to your page display. You will then be able to export it as a CSV.

Comment: Thanks, I have had a workaround on customizing the views and my search form. However I figured out that the imported data (from the CSV or any other input method) should be able to render on a table after which I can sort or filter this data using filters (Which I have already configured) of course with the search form being there too. I'd like to know if I'm on the right track on achieving that or what extra tweaks do I have to add?

Comment: @kimaiga The search form you are referring to, is it the exposed filter or is it unrelated to the view?? But if I understand you correctly, I should have mentioned that you need to have the exact same settings/fields/filters etc as the page display in your data export display as well.

Comment: The search form is the exposed filter.

Comment: If your table is a custom table and not drupal tables like nodes, taxonomy etc, you can expose your table to views. Look at this example [here][1]. And look at the feeds module, for importing csv into Drupal. I think this way you will not need much customizing and work with views just as it comes.

[1]:https://www.sitepoint.com/exposing-tables-views-drupal-7